# How to set Programmatically Min/Max value in DatagridviewIntegerInputColumn?

Tags: c#, winforms, dotnetbar

**I want set MaxValue to DataGridViewIntInputColumn , After an hour of research. I could not find a solution , I can edit it from the (collection) of data gridview :**

[image: Edit Columns]

but I want Edit it Programmatically please HELP !

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly! - Also: I can't find anything on either `DataGridViewIntInputColumn` or on `DatagridviewIntegerInputColumn`. Can you explain what you are talking about (and/or correct the typos?)

Comment: The usual approach would be to set a test value in the designer and then have a look at the resulting code in the designer.cs file..

Comment: You must do that like Column3.MaxValue = ... in your code.

Comment: @TaW i mean integer , because int = number integer , and I'm targeting Winforms + DotNetBar , in collection of `dataGridViewX` you can find `DataGridViewIntegerInputColumn` , just I could not set Max/Min value !!

Comment: You ought to have tagged that !! I have added the tags for you. Did you try the trick I mentioned?